# Does fstream class maintain two buffers while working with files in "ios::in|ios::out" mode? C++

Tags: c++, file-io, buffer, fstream, file-pointer

I red from the link:[`tellg()` and `tellp()` return same value](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/46312/)

**My conclusion:-**

1)if there is only one pointer maintained there must be only one buffer which is used for both input and output

2)there are two buffers one for input and other for output and have separate *get* and *put* pointer respectively and whenever *get* pointer moves, *put* pointer moves by same no. of bytes or vice versa.

**Which conclusion is correct?**

Comment: #1 seems correct.

Comment: sure? Please post a link .